# Обновить данные в TableView после закрытия модального окна

Tags: java, javafx

Есть главная сцена с TableView, куда выводятся данные из списка. Есть модальное окно где в БД добавляется новая запись. Как после добавления нового элемента, обновить данные в TableView?

Может быть есть какой-то метод, который позволяет узнавать активно ли какое-то окно или еще что-то?

MainController

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private ComboBox categoryComboBox;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Phone> phonesTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Phone, Integer> idColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Phone, String> modelColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Phone, Integer> priceColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Phone, String> categoryColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Phone, String> descriptionColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Phone, String> producerColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Phone, Integer> statusColumn;

    //Главная сцена
    private Stage mainStage;



    //Сцена редактирования информации
    private Stage editStage;
    //Контроллер сцены редактирования
    EditController editController;
    //Загрузчик для сцены редактирования
    private FXMLLoader fxmlEditLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    //Parent для сцены редактирования
    Parent fxmlEdit;

    //Сцена добавления информации
    private Stage addStage;
    //Контроллер сцены добавления
    AddController addController;
    //Загрузчик для сцены добавления
    private FXMLLoader fxmlAddLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    //Parent для сцены добавления
    Parent fxmlAdd;

    //Телефоны
    private Phones phonesList = new Phones();
    //Категории
    private Categories categoriesList = new Categories();

    //Фильтруемый список. Нужен для фильтрации списка телефонов, когда в выпадающем списке будет выбираться определенная категория
    private FilteredList<Phone> filteredList = new FilteredList<Phone>(phonesList.getPhoneList(), phone -> true);

    //Метод устанавливает подмостки для главного контроллера
    public void setMainStage(Stage mainStage) {
        this.mainStage = mainStage;
    }

    //Метод инициализации
    public void initialize() throws SQLException, IOException {
        fillPhonesTable();
        fillCategoryComboBox();

        //Выводим в колонки TableView данные из списка
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Phone, Integer>("id"));
        modelColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Phone, String>("model"));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Phone, Integer>("price"));
        categoryColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Phone, String>("category"));
        descriptionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Phone, String>("description"));
        producerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Phone, String>("producer"));
        statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Phone, Integer>("status"));

        comboBoxFilter(categoryComboBox);

        //Сортируемый список, чтобы при нажатии на колонку в TableView данные сортировались
        SortedList<Phone> sortedList = new SortedList<Phone>(filteredList);
        //Выполняет сортировку данных в TableView при нажатии на заголовок колонки в TavleView
        sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(phonesTable.comparatorProperty());

        //Выводим отсортированные и отфильтрованные данные в TableView
        phonesTable.setItems(sortedList);

        //Загружаем сцену добавления
        addSceneLoader();
    }

    private void fillPhonesTable() throws SQLException, IOException {
        //Заполняем список phonesList телефонами
        phonesList.fillPhoneList();

        //При двойном клике на запись открываем окно для редактирования информации
        phonesTable.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    //Устанавливаем методику. Т.е. передаем в сцену редактирования данные о выбранной модели телефона
                    editController.setPhone((Phone) phonesTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

                    //Вызываем метод, для отображения модального окна
                    editSceneShow();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    //Загружает сцену добавления
    private void addSceneLoader() {
        try {
            fxmlAddLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/phonesapp/fxml/addScene.fxml"));
            fxmlAdd = fxmlAddLoader.load();
            addController = fxmlAddLoader.getController();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Показывает сцену добавления
    private void addSceneShow() {
        if (addStage == null) {
            addStage = new Stage();
            addStage.setTitle("Добавление новой модели");
            addStage.setMaxWidth(800);
            addStage.setMaxHeight(500);
            addStage.setMinWidth(800);
            addStage.setMinHeight(500);
            addStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            addStage.setResizable(false);
            addStage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlAdd));
            //Здесь выявляем что для этого модального окна родительским окном является mainStage
            addStage.initOwner(mainStage);
        }

        addStage.showAndWait();
    }

    //Метод показывает сцену добавления новой модели телефона
    public void onAddClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        addSceneShow();
    }

}
```

AddController

```
public class AddController {
    @FXML
    private TextField txtModel;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPrice;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox comboboxCategory;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtDescription;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox comboboxProducer;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox comboboxStatus;

    //Категории
    private Categories categoriesList = new Categories();

    //Производители
    private Producers producersList = new Producers();

    //Телефоны
    private Phones phonesList = new Phones();

    //Список для выпадающего списка статуса
    private ObservableList<String> statusList;

    public void initialize() throws SQLException, IOException {
        //Заполняем выпадающий список названиями категорий
        fillComboboxCategory();
        //Заполняем выпадающий список названиями производителей
        fillComboboxProducer();

        //Список типа ObservableList для выпадающего списка для статуса
        statusList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        statusList.add("Нет в продаже");
        statusList.add("В продаже");

        //Заполняем ComboBox для статуса
        comboboxStatus.setItems(statusList);
    }

    //Данный метод заполняет выпадающий список comboboxCategory названиями категорий из таблицы БД
    private void fillComboboxCategory() throws SQLException, IOException {
        //Заполняем список названиями категорий
        categoriesList.fillCategoryList();
        //Устанавливаем для ComboBox значения из списка, который получили на предыдущем этапе.
        comboboxCategory.setItems(categoriesList.getCategoryList());
    }

    //Данный метод заполняет выпадающий список comboboxProducer названиями категорий из таблицы БД
    private void fillComboboxProducer() throws SQLException, IOException {
        //Заполняем список названиями категорий
        producersList.fillProducerList();
        //Устанавливаем для ComboBox значения из списка, который получили на предыдущем этапе.
        comboboxProducer.setItems(producersList.getProducerList());
    }

    public void onOK(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws SQLException, IOException {
        try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {
            //Подготовленный запрос на добавление записи в таблицу БД
            String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO phones (model, price, categoryID, description, producerID, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);

            //Получаем индекс вхождения категории телефона в список категорий. И т.к. нумерация нацинается в коллекциях с нуля, то увеличиваем на 1
            int categoryIndex = categoriesList.getCategoryList().indexOf(comboboxCategory.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()) + 1;
            //Тоже самое и для списка производителей
            int producerIndex = producersList.getProducerList().indexOf(comboboxProducer.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()) + 1;

            //Для статуса
            int statusIndex = statusList.indexOf(comboboxStatus.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

            if (txtModel.getText().isEmpty() || txtPrice.getText().isEmpty() || comboboxCategory.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()
                    || comboboxStatus.getSelectionModel().isEmpty() || comboboxProducer.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Информация");
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Заполните все поля!");

                alert.showAndWait();
            }

            preparedStatement.setString(1, txtModel.getText());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(txtPrice.getText()));
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, categoryIndex);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, txtDescription.getText());
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, producerIndex);
            preparedStatement.setInt(6, statusIndex);

            //Выполняем сам запрос
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            onCancel(actionEvent);
        }
    }

    public void onCancel(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        //Получаем узел
        Node source = (Node) actionEvent.getSource();
        //Получаем подмостки
        Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        //Скрываем окно
        stage.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо назначить слушателя ChangeListener на изменяемые объекты. 
И загрузку второстепенной сцены (addSceneLoader()) лучше вынести из контроллера и обращаться к методу экземпляра main.
Неплохой пример по созданию JavaFx - приложения: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать